# ContextMenu on a rounded LinearGradient produces sharp edges in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, contextmenu, gradient

I have the following view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red]), startPoint: .topTrailing, endPoint: .bottomLeading)
            .cornerRadius(16)
            .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
            .contextMenu {
                Button("", action: {})
            }
    }

}
```

However, when the ContextMenu is invoked, the edges are not rounded:

[image]

I've tried several things, such as:

- Applying the `clipShape` modifier to clip it to a `RoundedRectangle`
- Wrapping the gradient as the background of a RoundedRectangle view
- Using a Color instead of a LinearGradient (which works as expected, but not what I need)

However none work. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add the following code after `.frame(...)`:

```
.contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous))
```

Answer (score 14):

#### Updated for `Swift 5.7.2`

**TLDR:**

```
// Use the method that takes in ContentShapeKinds
.contentShape(.contextMenuPreview, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
```

Placed *after* `.frame(...)`, and *before* `.contextMenu { ... }`

---

**Detailed example:**

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .zero) {
            Text("Hello")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.title)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 120)
        // These corner radii should match
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).foregroundColor(.blue))
        .contentShape(.contextMenuPreview, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
        .contextMenu {
            Button("Look!") { print("We did it!") }
        }
    }
```

The above code produces a `contextMenu` that looks like this:

[image]

... instead of this:

[image]

Comment: This answer works for me, while the other one doesn't.

Comment: Note that `.contextMenuPreview` is for iOS 15 and later.